# CSS line-spacing: Not Applied in <span> Element

Tags: html, css

I have an intractable, at least for me, HTML/CSS problem.  Here is a bit of a web page I'm currently developing:

[image: Screen shot showing apparently pathological line spacing in the fine print.]

(The whole page is here: http://www.professorbrown.net/ but has now been changed as suggested in the accepted answer.)
Note that the "fine print" at the bottom has the same line spacing as the body copy, and I can't fix it.  It looks the same in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, so it has to be an error in my work.

The CSS is: `.fine {font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.1;}`  The markup is `<span class="fine">`.

Using the inspector function of both Chrome and Firefox shows the computed CSS for font-size as 10px, which is correct, and the line-height as 11px, which is what I intended, but clearly not what's displayed.  Measurement says the displayed line height is about 32px, which is the same as the body copy above the fine print.  Margin, border, and padding for the fine print are all zero. HTML and CSS validate using validator.nu and Jigsaw.  There are style sheets from Skeleton, Superfish, and Slick linked in.  I've commented them out one by one with no change in the error.

Please tell me what I've done wrong or give me some help with further debugging.

(Note: This is still a development project, so TLS is not enabled and the images have watermarks because I haven't licensed them yet.  I know both things must be done before "production.")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `span` won't take on `line-height` correctly due to how its display property works if it is inside a `div` with defined `font-size` or `line-height` css. You can either change your `span` to a `div` or, you can add `display:block` to your `.line`'s css class to change the display behavior.

e.g.

`.fine {font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.1; display:block;}`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've edited the question to make your answer easier to find for the next person who needs it.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this answer because the linked page has change (which is why the question will eventually be closed and deleted). `line-height` works on spans just fine but we may never know why.

Comment: @Rob clarified a little

Comment: @Rob  The linked page has changed because Matti Price gave me the answer.  With `<span>` as shown in the question, `line-height:` did not take effect.  Changing `<span>` to `<div>` produced the desired result.  The answer not only works, it makes perfect sense when you consider the difference between inline and block elements.

Comment: @BobBrown That the markup in the link changed is the reason you are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and not a link to your site or any third party site.